# C# LoadImage returns error 1813

Tags: c#, dll, resources

I try to load an image from `imgres32.dll`. I'm trying to do it like this:

Load the dll:

```
dll_h = LoadLibrary(@"C:\Windows\System32\imgres32.dll");
```

Pass the handle to my function which does the ressource loading:

```
Bitmap b = GetImageResource(dll_h, "1002");
```

The function looks like this:

```
static Bitmap GetImageResource(IntPtr handle, string resourceId)
{
    IntPtr img_ptr = NativeMethods.LoadImage(handle, resourceId, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, 0);

    if (img_ptr == IntPtr.Zero)
        throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception((int)NativeMethods.GetLastError());

    return Image.FromHbitmap(img_ptr);
}
```

No matter which parameters I enter, I always get error code 1813 meaning

> The specified resource type cannot be found in the image file.

When I open the file in Visual Studio, I see a folder called `Icon` containing an Image with id `1002`.

[image]

When I click it, it shows me several Bitmap images contained, in different resolutions, containing one with resolution `16 x 16`. But when I call

```
LoadImage(handle, resourceId, IMAGE_BITMAP, 16, 16, 0);
```

Neither this not any other parameter combination does work, I always get error `1813`.

`IMAGE_BITMAP` is a constant int set to `0` like documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648045(v=vs.85).aspx), same with `IMAGE_ICON` and `IMAGE_CURSOR` but none of them works.

Help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should prefix the resource Id with #. Call it this way:

```
GetImageResource(dll_h, "#1002");
```

Comment: That's right. Or you could imitate the MAKEINTRESOURCE macro by passing an unsigned int to the native LoadImage method instead of a string: `[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)] public static extern IntPtr LoadImage(IntPtr hinst, uint uId, uint uType, int cxDesired, int cyDesired, uint fuLoad);` Then you can just use the integer 1002.